# Optional chaining access two level deep using variables in one line? E.g. `a[b]?[c]?.d`

Tags: typescript

Here is my current solution:

```js
const fn = (a: {[k: string]: any}, b: string, c: string) => {
  const temp = a[b] ?? {}
  return temp[c]?.d
}
```

Is it possible to do in one chain call (no `??`)? `a[b]?[c]?.d` is not valid syntax.

Comment: You can use `?.[prop]`, so `a[b]?.[c]?.d`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Optional_chaining_with_expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but it should be

```
const fn = (a: {[k: string]: any}, b: string, c: string) => {
  return a[b]?.[c]?.d
}
```